# Desele border on mouseout

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-manipulation

Add a pink border to a cell when the mouse is over

```
 let TH = documenter code hereent.getElementsByTagName('th');
       for (i = 0; i < TH.length; i++) {
           TH[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
             if(e.target) {
              this.style.border = '5px solid pink';


             } else {
              this.style.border = 'none';
             }

            });
        }
```

When I mouseout it's still to be the same pink color ( border ). How to fix it ?

Comment: Don't you miss an else? `if(e.target) {
          this.style.border = 'none';
         }
         else this.style.border = '5px solid pink';`

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "td" ).hover(
    function() {
        $( this ).addClass( "hover" );
    }, function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "hover" );
    }
);

//then you can add specific style for hover on a css file
```

Comment: When you provide code, please include an explanation that tells the OP exactly *what* is happening.